# is 'on submit ' grammatically correct?

Tags: expressions

Can we use ***on submit*** in the meaning of ***after validation*** ?

> On submit value a notification will be displayed

Comment: You want to say "on *submission*", or even "*upon submission*". Let's reserve `onSubmit()` for our JavaScript treatise.

Comment: @DanBron, that should be an answer.

Comment: Even if *on submit* were perfectly fine, *on submit value* certainly isn't. You want *on submitting a value*, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sentence "On submitting the value..." or "On submission of the value..." is correct. 'On submit' doesn't look grammatical here. It can be used in other circumstances like this: For example (need help *on submit* action when rendering the form as HTML).